# Adding months to a input date

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date-format

My question is how can I add 6 months into a date input on a textbox1 with a date format of "yyyymmdd".
 I tried it with the following code below but I am having a different answer.
I input "20130703" I am getting this answer: "20140003"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputString = textBox1.Text;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "yyyymmdd", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dt = DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(6);
    textBox2.Text = dt.ToString("yyyymmdd");
}
```

Comment: you have overwritten the inputted date with the current date plus 6 months (and using wrong format specifier: should be MM )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your date format is wrong (should be `MM`) and you don't need to use `DateTime.Now` as it's overwriting the `dt` value you parsed.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt = dt.AddMonths(6);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
            string inputString = textBox1.Text;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            dt = dt.AddMonths(6);
            textBox2.Text = dt.ToString("yyyymmdd");
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to add 6 months to the parsed date, and not 6 months to today's date? Try the above code

Comment: Yes, like @keyboardP pointed out - it's also related to the invalid format pattern

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string inputString = textBox1.Text;
     DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     dt = dt.Date.AddMonths(6);
     textBox2.Text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

Please note the format.